# Set variable with value = substring of another variable

Tags: nginx

Can I use regexps or functions when creating variables? For example, I want to redirect some ports range (e.g., 7xxx -> 5xxx), but I would like do not create many servers - just one like this:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:7000-7200;
    listen 7000-7200;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {

        set $port 5${server_port:2};
        # or any substring function:
        set $port 5${substring($server_port,2)};
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:$port/;
    }
}
```

i.e. **$port** is equal **$server_port** replacing the first character to symbol '5'. Can I do this?

Thank you for advance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive for this:

```
map $server_port $port {
    ~^.(.+)$ 5$1;
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:$port/;
    }
}
```